# Diferentes contadores en un mismo emplazamiento

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Quiero mostrar cuatro contadores en una misma página, pero me gustaría que se mostrasen de forma consecutiva. Cuando termine uno se muestre el siguiente y así hasta el final y volver al inicio, que se reproduzca en modo bucle.

Tampoco necesito que la función se active cuando hago scroll, ya me sirve con sólo cargar la página.

No se si he conseguido explicarme con claridad.

Lo que tengo ahora montado es lo siguiente:

```js
var a = 0;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var oTop = $('#counter').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
    if (a == 0 && $(window).scrollTop() > oTop) {
        $('.counter-value').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
            $({
                countNum: $this.text()
            }).animate({
                countNum: countTo
            },
                {
                    duration: 4000,
                    easing: 'swing',
                    step: function () {
                        $this.text((Math.floor(this.countNum).toLocaleString("en-US")) + $this.attr('data-character'));
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        $this.text((this.countNum.toLocaleString("en-US")) + $this.attr('data-character'));
                    }
                });
        });
        a = 1;
    }
});
```

```css
.counter-value-1, .counter-value-2, .counter-value-3, .counter-value-4 { 
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 17px 0;
}
.counter-value-1:after, .counter-value-2:after, .counter-value-3:after, .counter-value-4:after  {
    content: attr(data-desc);
    display: block;
    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter">
    <div class="sqs-col sqs-col-3 counter-value-1 counter-value" data-character="%" data-count="93" data-desc="User interaction with insights">0</div>
    <div class="sqs-col sqs-col-3 counter-value-2 counter-value" data-character="%" data-count="24" data-desc="Cross selling ratio">0</div>
    <div class="sqs-col sqs-col-3 counter-value-3 counter-value" data-character="%" data-count="20" data-desc="Customer engagement increase">0</div>
    <div class="sqs-col sqs-col-3 counter-value-4 counter-value" data-character="Months" data-count="3" data-desc="Time to go live leveraging SaaS">0</div>
</div>
```

Muchas gracias por adelantado!!

Comment: Hola Juanma, ¿será queres crear un carousel? ¿como esperas que sea la animación? de arriba hacia abajo, de derecha a izquierda, o al revez de alguna de las dos?

Comment: Hola @Marcos:
En disposición sería algo similar a esta imagen que adjunto:
[enlace](https://strands.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/Contador_KPIs_Def.gif)

Entiendo que el efecto de desplazamiento de los números es algo más laborioso, pero creo que la transición entre los diferentes contadores podría ser similar.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos por el interés, finalmente lo pude solucionar.
Comparto el código por si alguien puede hacer uso de él:

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function animateCounter($counter) {
                var countTo = $counter.attr('data-count');
                $counter.fadeIn(500, function () {
                    $({ countNum: $counter.text() }).animate({
                        countNum: countTo
                    }, {
                        duration: 4000,
                        easing: 'swing',
                        step: function () {
                            $counter.text((Math.floor(this.countNum).toLocaleString("en-US")) + $counter.attr('data-character'));
                        },
                        complete: function () {
                            $counter.text((this.countNum.toLocaleString("en-US")) + $counter.attr('data-character'));
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                $counter.fadeOut(500, function () {
                                    $counter.text('0'); // Reiniciar el contador
                                    var $nextCounter = $counter.next('.counter-value');
                                    if ($nextCounter.length > 0) {
                                        animateCounter($nextCounter); // Repetir el contador siguiente después de 2.5 segundos
                                    } else {
                                        animateCounter($('.counter-value').first()); // Si no hay siguiente, reiniciar desde el principio
                                    }
                                });
                            }, 2500);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }

            animateCounter($('.counter-value').first()); // Comenzar con el primer contador
        });
```

```css
    .counter-value {
            font-family: 'Poppins',Helvetica,Arial,Lucida,sans-serif;
            font-size: 170px;
            color: #023642;
            line-height: 1.1em;
            text-align: right;
            padding: 17px 0;
            display: none; /* Ocultamos todos los contadores inicialmente */
            transition: transform 1s ease; 
            font-weight: 600;
        }


        .counter-value:after {
            content: attr(data-desc);
            display: block;
            text-transform: none;
            font-size: 30px;
            color: #023642;
            line-height: 1.1em;
            font-weight: 500;
        }
```

```html
    <div id="counter">
        <div class="counter-value counter-value-1" data-character="%" data-count="93" data-desc="User interaction with insights">0</div>
        <div class="counter-value counter-value-2" data-character="%" data-count="24" data-desc="Cross selling ratio">93</div>
        <div class="counter-value counter-value-3" data-character="%" data-count="20" data-desc="Customer engagement increase">24</div>
        <div class="counter-value counter-value-4" data-character="Months" data-count="3" data-desc="Time to go live leveraging SaaS">20</div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Los snippets (así como el que colocaron en una edición a tu pregunta), se agregan con el botón que indica `<>`.

Comment: Muchas gracias @padaleiana!
Solucionado!!